# ReactJS: How can I center the placeholder and text for Material-UI's <DatePicker/>?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, datepicker

I am using `<DatePicker/>` from http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker for my ReactJS project and would like to center align the placeholder and input text. So I tried `textAlign:'center'` to `textFieldStyle` and the regular `style` properties, yet still did not work.

Is there a way to implement the center alignment?

Thank you

**EDIT**

```
//So inside tried style={{textAlign: 'center'}} and textFieldStyle={{textAlign: 'center}} but neither worked
<DatePicker hintText="Choose Date" container="inline" />
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try using "inputStyle". That is the property used by TextField. Looking into the source code for DatePicker, it looks like it should pass that property verbatim into the enclosed TextField via JSX's spread attribue. So, give this a try...

```
<DatePicker
    hintText="Choose Date"
    container="inline"
    inputStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that Material-UI (for better or worse) decided to in-line all of their styles, and many of them are in inner div's that aren't overidden by JSX styling.

If you are not doing this programatically simply writing your styles in a CSS sheet and adding it to your project, and unfortunately using `!important` is probably the easiest way.

If it does have to be programatic (as in your business logic is dictating what your CSS should be), you can get try wading into writing a stylesheet in your JavaScript and appending it to the DOM.

Comment: sorry but for better clarification, could you show an example of your first suggestion?